# Handling \x01 received from Flash's ExternalInterface

Tags: c#, flash, byte

I'm receiving data from a Flash component embedded in a Windows Form. Unfortunately, if the data returned from the socket contains any of the following characters, the call to loadXml below fails:

This is the callback method I have to receive data from the socket (via ExternalInterface in the Flash component).

```
private void player_FlashCall(object sender, _IShockwaveFlashEvents_FlashCallEvent e)
{
            String output = e.request;
            //output = CleanInvalidXmlChars(output);
            XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
            document.LoadXml(output);

            XmlAttributeCollection attributes = document.FirstChild.Attributes;
            String command = attributes.Item(0).InnerText;              
            XmlNodeList list = document.GetElementsByTagName("arguments");               
            process(list[0].InnerText);
```

I had a method to replace the characters with text (CleanInvalidXmlChars), but I don't think this is the right approach.

How can I load this data into an XML file, as this makes separating the method name, paramter names and parameter types which are returned very easy to work with.

Would appreciate any help at all.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the “XML” contains any U+0001 (aka '\x01') or other similar characters, it is *not a valid XML*. There is no way you can include those characters in XML (well, in XML 1.0, anyway). See [the XML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#charsets). If you need to pass e.g. binary data in XML, you need to convert them to a proper form, e.g. using Base-64.

If the data does contain those invalid characters, it is not XML, and therefore cannot be read using standard XML tools (I don’t think any of the standard .NET classes allows you to override that behavior). You can either replace all those characters (these are basically all control characters (U+0000 through U+001F) except U+0009 (tab), U+000A and U+000D (CR+LF), plus U+FFFE and U+FFFF (noncharacters)) prior to use as you tried – you could devise a safe transformation which would not lose any data (e.g. first replace all @ characters with @0040, then replace any invalid character with @xxxx where xxxx is its code, and when processing the parsed XML data, replace all @xxxx back).

Another option is to drop the XML idea and just process it as a string. Just for inspiration, see e.g. [this piece of code](http://code.google.com/p/msfast/source/browse/trunk/src/MySpace.MSFast.GUI.Engine/Panels/GraphView/Controls/FlashPlayer.cs?r=5#357).